# what are some specific criteria for evaluating a piece of fiction that can be used repeatedly?

Tags: criticism

Can you provide list of specific items you use to evaluate whether or not a piece of fiction is good or bad?

For example, if you really had to explain why a piece of fiction were terrible what criteria might you use to analyze it in order to inform the writer without (blatantly) hurting her feelings?

Suppose you had something like the following excerpt and you had to evaluate it.

> She needed him.  And he was nowhere to be found.
>   There was no one
>   else she could rely on.  No one like her brother.  No one else at all,
>   now that the New Republic stood on the verge of implosion, of
>   destruction, of complete collapse.
>
> They had thought that with the fall
>   of the Empire it would all be so easy.  That people would understand
>   the need for patience, that time would be required to rebuild that
>   which the Empire had taken away.Ψ

```
Ψ Star Wars: The Force Awakens (page 1)
```

Comment: The problem is that each piece of fiction has its own goals (and we're not even getting into how different media like novels/stories/TV shows/movies serve different ends). Does the creator intend to amuse? provoke? titillate? Is the piece for kids? Is it satire? SF? noir? steampunk? stream-of-consciousness? There is no Ur-list of criteria which any work of fiction could tick off to be "good." Some people love Raymond Carver's brusqueness; others like Cormac McCarthy. I can't read either. That doesn't make them good or bad.

Comment: Just in your excerpt above: I don't find it unreadable. A little boring and simple, maybe. But for a tween novelization of a movie, it might be perfect. So you can't claim it's "good" or "bad" until you know what it's trying to accomplish. Did it meet its goals? That's about the only yardstick you can use.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Great comments as always.  You've helped to further my question, because there have to be some basic criteria or else even language wouldn't matter and we'd just say, "I'm sorry, it's art!" and then there'd just be people to tell us what is good and each reader would be unable to comment about it.  For example - "meebo gleeptum suffus dof"  You don't know what my target is so you have no way to tell me that my sample sentence is bad.  But that becomes ridiculous. I hope this doesn't sound combative.  It's an interesting thing to me. I believe there are certain criteria (framework)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a volunteer reader for a literary journal, so I read and evaluate a ton of stories. (Very few are "terrible," but terrible usually shows up in the first sentences.) Of course, the purpose of the story and the needs of the reader/publication both come into play, but I can come up with a few things that make a story less than great (for me). (I'm guilty of this stuff myself, and have to fix it in editing.)

**An excess of stuff that doesn't go anywhere.** Many early drafts include a lot of "throat clearing." We see the characters meet and exchange pleasantries and talk about Aunt Mary's goiter for a page and a half until they finally say the thing the reader needs to hear. We don't need to read the entire conversation; just give us the important bits. We don't need to see the character wake up and get dressed; just get him out the door. We don't need detail about every knick knack in the room; just set the scene and get the characters doing something. [Elmore Leonard said](https://www.writingclasses.com/toolbox/tips-masters/elmore-leonard-10-rules-for-good-writing), "Try to leave out the part that readers tend to skip."

**A lack of action.** I don't mean car chases, but just human action. What is the character doing as she talks? Making coffee? Changing a car's oil? Fidgeting? Little actions break up the dialog and, when done well, show the character's state of mind. "Henry's hands shook so much that he dropped the spoon." That reads better than "Henry was nervous." and *much better* than "'I understand,' Henry said nervously."

**Keeping secrets from the reader.** This irks me so much. All the characters know what's going on, but the author is keeping it from the reader in order to spring it on them at the end. That comes across as manipulative. If your story needs a big reveal, then make the reveal to one of the characters, not to the reader.

My advice to avoid this stuff is to (1) get yourself some good readers, (2) do enough revision, and (3) read a lot. A LOT. Pay attention to how your favorite authors write.

Comment: Those are three great points. Rewriting to remove that type of stuff would make huge improvements in most stories. Excellent explanations. And actually, The Force Awakens beginning commits all three of those literary crimes which is why it is so difficult and boring to read. :)

Comment: I do a fair amount of beta reading, and I agree keeping secrets from the reader is the most annoying common habit I see. You think you're being clever? No,  you're throwing away a good potential plot line and being lazy about building drama.

Answer (score 1):

The great difficulty here is that **there are no absolutes**. The same piece could be achingly poetic or achingly dull, depending on whether it's part of a literary drama or a high-octane adventure.

That makes it very difficult to give "specific criteria" for evaluating. There's no rubric that covers hard SF *and* slipstream.

Nonetheless, you *can* evaluate fiction, and justify your evaluations. I've got some experience both as a beta reader and as a reviewer, and I've got two insights I think will address your question.

### The best evaluation you can give is your own reaction.

Precisely because fiction is so subjective, and has so many different shapes and forms, you don't really want to say "This piece was terrible." You want to say "This piece was terrible *for me*." What you want to get across is not how the story fails, but how it failed *you*.

The reason this is helpful is because your response is subjective, but it's also factual. It may be wrong to say "This is boring," "this is ludicrous," "this is heavy-handed," because other people may react differently -- but it is perfectly correct, and indeed unarguable, that *you* found it boring, or ludicrous, or heavy-handed.

The better you are able to describe your own reaction while reading, the more helpful your feedback will be. Consider, just as an example:

> At the beginning I was interested in how Sarah's relation with the stepmother would develop. Then when Sarah's friend won the lottery it was funny at the beginning, but then I got tired of it as it dragged on. Then when the stepmother stole the lottery ticket, that really jarred me, because it didn't seem to me like something she'd do; it didn't fit in for me with why the conflict was interesting to begin with. That kind of threw me out of the story; I don't have many reactions to the final climax because by that point I just didn't care about Sarah and her stepmother any more.
>
> You had a lot of references to downtown Miami that I thought were really well done; I recognized a bunch of them and I think you nailed them.
>
> The little brother was really annoying; I don't know if that's what you were going for, but I just wanted him *gone* every time he showed up.

As much as you're capable of, **be specific** on what you're reacting to and what the reaction is. "The stepmother stealing the lottery ticket felt out-of-character to me" is much clearer than "I felt like the stepmother's character wasn't consistent and bounced all over the place."

The clearer you are, the more specific you are, and as long as you focus on your own reaction, you will find that your feedback is helpful and also avoids being insulting. You're not dismissing the person's work or ripping it apart, you're keying onto particular details and reacting to them naturally.

This kind of criticism also makes it very clear how in one story you can say "OMG this car chase is absolutely AWESOME I am LOVING IT" and in another you can say "The car chase was very energetic but felt detached from the rest of the story, and I was frustrated because I was really waiting to find out what happened to Dianne."

### The criteria to evaluate by is "did this piece achieve its intended goal."

The reasons there are no hard-fast rules is because different stories are trying to do different things. "I didn't connect with the characters" may be irrelevant if you're going for zany satire; "There's no plot" might be the whole point of naturalistic literary fiction; "This isn't scientifically accurate" may not be an actual issue to the author's intended audience.

For every story you're evaluating, you must first answer the question: **What is this story trying to do? What is it trying to be?**

Once you can answer that question, *then* you can start asking "Does it accomplish that?".

That's you're specific criteria: Identify the goal. Then ask whether it achieves that goal, how it succeeds and how it fails.

(If you cannot identify the goal, that's an important criticism in and of itself. The questions "Where is this going? Why am I reading this?" are important ones, and often missed.)

You can break this down - identify the goal for a particular scene or snippet:

> The opening of *The Force Awakens* is obviously trying to draw us into the novel. It opens on Leia, introducing her as being in a precarious position and desperate for Luke's support. `<-- This is the snippet's goal.`
>
> It took me a few read-overs to realize that we're meant to identify Leia and Luke. To me, this felt really generic and bombastic - broad statements like "she needed him" and "the New Republic stood on the verge of implosion" don't really set a scene for me; they just seem like McGuffins whose details will be filled in later. "She needed X," "something bad is happening to Y". I'd much prefer opening on strong specifics that ground me in a scene, or speak about concrete action rather than broad, vague "Save the New Republic."
>
> On the other hand, the trick of figuring out who's being spoken of is nice - slotting the beloved characters into new positions, letting that click.
>
> Let's be honest; nobody who reads the first page of a Star Wars novelization is going to put it down at the first page. This sets the scene, establishes tension, re-introduces characters we know. I don't like the vagueness, but you're probably fine as long as you bring us to a concrete scene soon. `<-- This is your evaluation - it does an OK job of getting the reader to turn the page, which is all it's meant to do.`

Comment: Standback:  I really enjoyed reading your answer. I'm going to go through it again later when I can look at it in more detail. Really like the final analysis example you gave for SW excerpt. I like the idea of an "overall" rating (for me it was not great because or for me I really enjoyed it because...).  The I'd like to also add some other specific target items I have in mind for providing specifics of why I did or didn't think the writing was great.  Thanks.

Comment: Really glad you liked. :) There definitely *are* common issues you could use as target items; the thing is that they don't always apply. In my experience it's best to *know* the common issues (so you recognize them and react to them), but for each piece, you need to figure out _which_ common issue(s) you need to focus on to make _this_ critique work and make sense. Saying 'I've got a list of ten problems and you've hit 3, 4, and 7" can come out much less clear, because the writer doesn't trust your list like you do! :P

Comment: this is excellent, and a much more thorough breakdown and explanation of what I was getting at in my comments. Nicely done!